# GroupShortNameBinding adds a bullet point - how to remove

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have enabled Grouping on a list in iOS and added an Alphabet index to each entry

However, even though it displays the letters correctly, it's showing me a bullet point delimeter between each one?

I want to get rid of these, can anyone advise how please?

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding allGames}" IsGroupingEnabled="True" GroupShortNameBinding="{Binding LETTER}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>

        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>

                <Label TextColor="Black" Text="{Binding GAME_NAME}"/>

                </ViewCell>

        </DataTemplate>

    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>
```

[image]

Code for adding the index key (alphabet) to the list

```xml
if (allGames == null)
{
allGames = new ObservableCollection<GAME_TBL>();

}

var services = new DataModels();

GAME_SELECTION _select = new GAME_SELECTION();

allGames = await services.Games(1, _select);

foreach (GAME_TBL _indexTable in allGames)

{
_indexTable.LETTER = _indexTable.GAME_NAME.Substring(0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Can you show a pic of the issue? Also, post the code that you have for the grouping, as well as the GroupingTemplate.

Comment: @MihailDuchev added both as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't remote the so-called "bullet points" - that is by design. The official term for that part is called `Jump list`.

What is happening behind the scenes is that you have too many grouped items. In this case, sometimes the phone's height can't fit all of them, so it is hiding some of the items behind the dots.

You can customize the list - change its color, etc, but the bullets can't be removed. However, what you can do is to reduce the count of your items, because I see some that are repeating - you have 3xS & 2xT, etc. If that is by design, then leave it like so. If not, try to better group the items.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to reduce the number of options there at the minute - all I want is simply an alphabetical list of letters but my first attempt to do so as you can see has resulted in duplicates that I don't want

Comment: you need to post the code you are using to generate the list

Comment: Added the code after the image above. From what I read, each entry in the list needs the key, so after my API has returned the results, I am adding the index letter to each entry. So I don't see why the group then lists the same letter (e.g. S) more than once?

Comment: This is not grouping of items. You simply iterate through all of the items and set their LETTER property to the first letter. This way, if you have 500 items, you will have 500 items in the list view under 1 group and 500 symbols at the right. You can see how you can group them in the official repo: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/master/UserInterface/ListView/Grouping or in this tutorial: https://xamarinhelp.com/xamarin-forms-listview-grouping

Comment: OK I think I understand now. Thanks

Comment: @MihailDuchev I am getting blank rows in the list each time an observable collection is added, almost like it wants to show a header or something? Can you suggest what cause might be?

Comment: Have you customized your [GroupHeaderTemplate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.listview.groupheadertemplate?view=xamarin-forms)?

Comment: No. Sorry, I misunderstood. If you have blank rows, then check your bindings. You have modified your collection's item source to a grouped collection, I guess. Then check again what you are binding to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216068/discussion-between-journeyman1234-and-mihail-duchev).